# How to Manipulate Dropdown placeholder, onFocus?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Am new to ReactJS. I need to make the "placeholder" which is set to "State" initially to Empty/Null when onClicked or onFocus and then when it's not focused on, it goes back to "State" again. Can someone help me with this, am very new to react so any help will be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Container, Button, Modal, Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";

const stateOptions = [
  { key: "AL", value: "AL", text: "Alabama" },
  { key: "NY", value: "NY", text: "New York" }
];
const App = () => (
  <Dropdown
    placeholder="State"
    fluid
    multiple
    search
    selection
    options={stateOptions}
  />
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: By "dropdown", you mean the `<select>` element?

Comment: That's correct. As shown in the code piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From React's perspective, `placeholder` is a `state` that needs to be changed according to user's actions (`onClick`, `onBlur`)

So create a state to hold `placeholder` value that need to change.

There are two ways (since v16.8.0 with the introduction of React Hooks).

### Using Class Component

```js
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  defaultPlaceholderState = "State";

  state = { placeholder: this.defaultPlaceholderState };

  clearPlaceholder = () => this.setState({ placeholder: "" });
  resetPlaceholder = () =>
    this.setState({ placeholder: this.defaultPlaceholderState });

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onClick={this.clearPlaceholder}
        onFocus={this.clearPlaceholder}
        onBlur={this.resetPlaceholder}
        placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
        fluid
        multiple
        search
        selection
        options={stateOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above, `placeholder` declared as a state with default value set to `this.defaultPlaceholderState`.

When a user clicks on the dropdown, `onClick` clears the `placeholder` value by setting it to an empty string. Same for `onFocus` when the Dropdown is on focus.

When a user clicks outside (`onBlur`), `resetPlaceHolder` sets the placeholder value to the default `this.defaultPlaceholderState`.

### Using Function Component with `useState` hook

React v16.8.0 introduces [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), which enables `Function Components` (not a Functional Component, as it refers to Functional Programming) to hold states.

You can use `React.useState` hook to hold `placeholder` value.

```js
const DropDownUsingHook = () => {
  const defaultPlaceholderState = "State";
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = React.useState(defaultPlaceholderState);

  const clearPlaceholder = () => setPlaceholder("");
  const resetPlaceholder = () => setPlaceholder(defaultPlaceholderState);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      onClick={clearPlaceholder}
      onFocus={clearPlaceholder}
      onBlur={resetPlaceholder}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      fluid
      multiple
      search
      selection
      options={stateOptions}
    />
  );
};
```

⚠ **Note**: Unlike the Class version, `clearPlaceholder`, `resetPlaceholder` methods and `placeholder` state don't use `this.` prefix.

The implementation is similar but you use useState hook to declare the state and the setter (`setPlaceholder`).

*Refer to the Hooks documentation, [Using State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for more info.*

You can play around with the working code on CodeSandbox.

[image: Edit so.answer.54652775]

Comment: May be am pushing a bit here, but what if I've multiple dropdown's ? Is a simpler way to achieve this or do I need to create unique placeholders for each of the dropdowns in state and then do what you've mentioned ? Please pardon my ignorance. :-)

Comment: No need for an apology as you ain't being ignorant and it's all part of learning 

If you have multiple dropdowns, pass a placeholder value as a prop to `DropDown` when you use it. e.g.) `<DropDown placeholder="State" />` or `<DropDown placeholder="City" />` and within `DropDown`, you would use `this.props.placeholder` to either initialize or use as a default value

Comment: I've updated the Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/x989rq45x4 - Updated `DropDown` to accept `placeholder` as a prop. If you need to use different `options`, you'd need to pass that as props too.

Comment: @fuman_t You're welcome.  Would you mark the answer as answered if it has solved the issue? 

Comment: I think I hit a bug , may be something to do with Sematic UI. When I click onto one of the drop down and click again (not selecting anything, but just clicking onto the input field the Cursor goes away and now nothing can't be typed in. This can also be reproduced by typing in something random and then click onto the input field again. The focus disappears and then nothing on the field could be edited.